# How can the carriage return \r\n in a text which is put in an HTML cell with Django be interpret as carriage return and not present the \r\n?

Tags: html, django, django-templates

I have as input a text block with several lines separated by \r\n.
I'm extracting the information with Django and putting into a model as TextField, e.g. `info = models.TextField()`

> b'Hey\r\n\r\nIn regards to your letter sent ...'

Inside a Django template I put the text into an HTML cell `{{ letter.info }}`
When the HTML table is presented, the text is shown as one line with the \r\n visible as part of text.

Is there a way to make that the text is presented in different lines? i.e. that the \r\n are interpreted as the carriage return and not presented raw?

I've tried some suggestions I found for similar questions, as using `style="white-space: break-space"` `pre-line`; `pre-wrap` but that did not work.
I've also tried to replace the `\r\n` with `<br/>`, but the raw 
 is presented instead and the line is not broken.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the culprit. The issue was that the input text was escaped, therefore what I saw in the text as \n \r \t was actually \\n \\r \\t and therefore all filters and formatting I was trying did not work.

One solution was to encode/decode with
`str.encode().decode('unicode-escape')`
but though this solution worked for the newlines and tabs, it did not work with apostrophes and with Swedish å ö ä

And after more research about unicode and utf-8 I realized the input I'm getting is formatted as bytes;
In this case, I have to treat the input I get as bytes, and then decode to utf-8.

`bytes_input = bytes(input_blob)`

`text = bytes_input.decode("utf-8")`

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the [linebreaks](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#linebreaks) filter?

Comment: Thanks for the advice! it looked promising, but it did not work for the text I have. I tried with other filters and they work (e.g. 'lower', 'linenumbers'), but for some reason the 'linebreaks' or 'linebreaksbr' did not work with the text I have. There is something weird in the text I have. I had extracted it from an e-mail body. I'll keep investigating if I get somewhere.